# Detect incoming UDP streams on Windows

Tags: windows, sockets, udp

A Windows app I use can list all incoming UDP streams and update the list as soon as I begin sending to a new port.  How can I do that in my own programs?

Comment: You probably need something like a low-level/promiscous capturing hook, such as the one employed by libpcap (used by Wireshark).  For every packet detected, check if the sender/recipient exists in your list, and if not then add it

Comment: Note that strictly speaking there is no such thing as a "UDP stream", only UDP packets.